# Spring Batch error: Impossible to insert NULL value in column 'STEP_EXECUTION_ID', table 'BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT'

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have this partition step:

```
@Bean
@JobScope
    public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String table) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get(table)
                .partitioner("IncrementalWorker", partitioner())
                .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler())
                .build();
    }
```

and this is the Handler:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(String table) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
        handler.setStep(IncrementalWorker(table));
        handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        try {
            handler.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return handler;
    }
```

and this is the slave step:

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step IncrementalWorker(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String name) throws Exception {
        SimpleStepBuilder<Table, Data> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalWorker " + name)
                .<Table, Data>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(oracleXmlIncrementalReader)
                .processor(new FastXmlProcessor())
                .writer(jsonWriter);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

but i always have this error:
**java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Impossible to insert NULL value in column 'STEP_EXECUTION_ID', table 'TESTFT.dbo.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT'. This column does not accept NULL values. INSERT failed.**

Here is the whole stuck trace:

> 2023-07-12 | 12:39:33.305 | s.b.c.j.SimpleStepHandler |  INFO | Executing step: [IncrementalXmlManager] 2023-07-12 | 12:39:33.497 |
> o.s.b.c.step.AbstractStep | ERROR | Encountered an error executing
> step IncrementalXmlManager in job extracteur
> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT
> INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT,
> STEP_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [null]; error code [0];
> Impossible d'insérer la valeur NULL dans la colonne
> 'STEP_EXECUTION_ID', table 'TESTFT.dbo.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT'.
> Cette colonne n'accepte pas les valeurs NULL. Échec de INSERT.; nested
> exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Impossible d'insérer la
> valeur NULL dans la colonne 'STEP_EXECUTION_ID', table
> 'TESTFT.dbo.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT'. Cette colonne n'accepte pas
> les valeurs NULL. Échec de INSERT.    at
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1542)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Impossible d'insérer la valeur NULL
> dans la colonne 'STEP_EXECUTION_ID', table
> 'TESTFT.dbo.BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT'. Cette colonne n'accepte pas
> les valeurs NULL. Échec de INSERT.    at
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:2145)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
> at
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$4(JdbcTemplate.java:1048)
> at
> org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
> ... 127 common frames omitted

is there is any solution ?

PS: when i run a SimpleStepBuilder instead of PartitionStepBuilder it works fine and here is my SimpleStepBuilder :

```
@Bean
@StepScope
  public Step Worker(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String name) throws Exception {
        SimpleStepBuilder<Table, Data> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("Worker " + name)
                .<Table, Data>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(oracleXmlReader)
                .processor(fastXmlProcessor())
                .writer(jsonWriter);
        return builder.build();
    }
```

**READER:** it is located in other class callse "XmlReader":

```
@Slf4j
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class})
@Component
public class XmlReader {
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("T")
    private DataSource dataSource;    
        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Table>
        oracleXmlIncrementalReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['QUERY']}") String query,
                                    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}") Long minValue) throws Exception
        {
            
            log.debug("[minValue - maxValue] : " + minValue);
            log.debug("[Reader Query] : \n" + query);
    
            JdbcCursorItemReader<Table> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            log.debug(String.format("Le paramètre FETCH_SIZE est %d", FETCH_SIZE));
            reader.setFetchSize(FETCH_SIZE);
            reader.setConnectionAutoCommit(false);
            reader.setSql(query);
            reader.setRowMapper(new XMLRowMapper());
            reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatement -> {
            preparedStatement.setLong(1, 1); preparedStatement.setLong(2, minValue); });
    
            SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Table> synchronizedReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
            synchronizedReader.setDelegate(reader);
            synchronizedReader.afterPropertiesSet();
            
            System.err.println(query);
            return synchronizedReader;
        }
```

**WRITER:**

```
@Component
@Import({BIDataSourceConfiguration.class})
@StepScope
public class JdbcWriter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("bi")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private final Renamer renamer = new Renamer();

    @Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}")
    String TableName;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Data> jsonWriter(){
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Data> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        writer.setSql(String.format("INSERT INTO raw%s (raw_id, raw_data) VALUES (?, ?)", renamer.biRenamer(this.TableName)));
        writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new TPreparedStatementSetter());
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return writer;
    }
}
```

**PARTITIONER:**

```
public class RowIdPartitioner implements Partitioner
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize)
    {
        //ora_hash(rowid, ? 5 gridSize (taskExecutor)) = ? 0 -> 4 (01234)partitioner
        //0 ==> n-1
        int targetSize = gridSize  - 1;

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<>();

        int number = 0;
        int start = 0;
        int end = targetSize - 1;

        while (start < gridSize)
        {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

            result.put("partition" + number, value);

            if (end >= gridSize)
            {
                end = gridSize;
            }

            value.putInt("minValue", start);
  //          value.putInt("maxValue", end);

            start += targetSize;
            end += targetSize;

            number++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

> EDIT: After the comments and the answer, i edited my code this way but it didn't resolve the issue

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ExtracteurSteps {

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    @StepScope
    SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Table>
            oracleXmlIncrementalReader;

    @Autowired
    @StepScope
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Data> jsonWriter;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FastXmlProcessor fastXmlProcessor(){
        return new FastXmlProcessor();
    }



    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step IncrementalWorker(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String name) throws Exception {
        SimpleStepBuilder<Table, Data> builder = stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalWorker " + name)
                .<Table, Data>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(oracleXmlIncrementalReader)
                .processor(fastXmlProcessor())
                .writer(jsonWriter);
        return builder.build();
    }


    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager " + table)
                .partitioner("IncrementalWorker " + table, partitioner())
                .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RowIdPartitioner partitioner() {
        return new RowIdPartitioner();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler() throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
        handler.setStep(IncrementalWorker(null));
        handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        try {
            handler.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return handler;
    }

}
```

> EDIT:
> I tried the solution described below:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class ExtracteurSteps {

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    @StepScope
    SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Table>
            oracleXmlIncrementalReader;

    @Autowired
    @StepScope
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Data> jsonWriter;

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FastXmlProcessor fastXmlProcessor(){
        return new FastXmlProcessor();
    }



    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Step IncrementalWorker(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String name) throws Exception {
        SimpleStepBuilder<Table, Data> builder = this.stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalWorker " + name)
                .<Table, Data>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
                .reader(oracleXmlIncrementalReader)
                .processor(fastXmlProcessor())
                .writer(jsonWriter);
        return builder.build();
    }


    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table, @Qualifier("IncrementalWorker") Step step) throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager " + table)
                .partitioner("IncrementalWorker " + table, partitioner())
                .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(step))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RowIdPartitioner partitioner() {
        return new RowIdPartitioner();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(Step step) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
        handler.setStep(step);
        handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        handler.afterPropertiesSet();

        return handler;
    }

}
```

and it showed me this error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-07-14 | 09:47:17.132 | ngFailureAnalysisReporter | ERROR | 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler in ExtracteurSteps required a single bean, but 9 were found:
Action:
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

So, I added `@Qualifier("IncrementalWorker")` to `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` and I get back again to the very same error with the same stuck

> EDIT:
> I modified the code this way:

```
@Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table, StepLocator stepLocator) throws Exception {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
                .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
                .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(stepLocator))
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public RowIdPartitioner partitioner() {
        return new RowIdPartitioner();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(StepLocator stepLocator) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
        handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
        handler.setStep(stepLocator.getStep("IncrementalWorker"));  // change this to match the name of the step
        handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        handler.afterPropertiesSet();
        return handler;
    }
```

which generated a new error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
> re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2023-07-14 |
> 11:22:25.396 | o.s.b.SpringApplication   | ERROR | Application run
> failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler' defined in
> class path resource [/Extracteur/Step/ExtracteurSteps.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.batch.core.partition.PartitionHandler]: Factory
> method 'XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler' threw exception; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.TDate': Scope 'job' is not
> active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
> this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder
> available for job scope   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
> at ExtractorApplication.main(ExtractorApplication.java:30) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.batch.core.partition.PartitionHandler]: Factory
> method 'XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler' threw exception; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.TDate': Scope 'job' is not
> active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
> this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder
> available for job scope   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
> ... 19 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException:
> Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.TDate': Scope 'job' is not
> active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
> this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder
> available for job scope   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195)
> at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy131.getName(Unknown Source)  at
> org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.getStep(SimpleJob.java:109)
> at
> Extracteur.Step.ExtracteurSteps.XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(ExtracteurSteps.java:87)
> at
> Extracteur.Step.ExtracteurSteps$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87903892.CGLIB$XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler$0()
> at
> Extracteur.Step.ExtracteurSteps$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87903892$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$284d2b1e.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
> at
> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
> at
> Extracteur.Step.ExtracteurSteps$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$87903892.XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler()
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
> ... 20 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job
> scope     at
> org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.getContext(JobScope.java:159)
> at
> org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.get(JobScope.java:92)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371)
> ... 36 common frames omitted

**PS: TDate is the first step in my job**

Comment: When does this error happen? Please share the full stack trace of the exception. Moreover, it is incorrect to scope a step bean. You should move late-binding to the component of the step (tasklet, reader, writer, partitioner, etc), and not the step itself.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks for your comment, you can find further details in the question, i updated it

Comment: The stacktrace seems truncated but it seems that `NULL` is being inserted in `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT.STEP_EXECUTION_ID`. This is probably due to late-binding which is triggered eagerly. The `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` should not be step-scoped, it does not use late binding. Please remove `@StepScope` on it and share your feedback. To help you efficiently, consider providing  a minimal example that reproduces the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine i tried before to removed it and i didn't resolve the problem, i even removed it for "IncrementalWorker" and the error always persists

Comment: If you have any more questions, you can contact me (starting with @VonC for me to be notified) on the [discussion chat space](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254495/discussion-between-maryem-neyli-and-vonc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[After discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254495/discussion-between-maryem-neyli-and-vonc):

> I want to confirm you that I have upgraded the app to spring boot to 3.1.1, spring batch 5 and sql server to 12.3.4jre17 and that resolved the problems!

---

Original answer with different suggestions:

As commented, the `PartitionHandler` should not be step-scoped because it is a part of a step, not a step itself. That could be the cause of the problem.

Spring Batch's `StepScope` and `JobScope` are a way to allow late binding of values, that is, binding values to parameters at runtime. That is often necessary for values that need to be different for each execution of a step or a job. For example, a reader might need to read from a different file each time a step runs, based on parameters passed to the job.

[`StepScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html) is meant for beans that have a lifecycle tied to a single step execution, such as readers, writers, and processors. The bean will be created at the beginning of the step and discarded at the end of the step.

A [`PartitionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/PartitionHandler.html), on the other hand, is a component that is used to manage the execution of partitions in a partitioned step. It is a part of a step (a partitioned step, specifically), but it is not a step itself, so it does not have a lifecycle tied to a single step execution. Therefore, it should not be step-scoped. Instead, it should be [singleton-scoped](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton), which is the default scope for Spring beans. A singleton-scoped bean is created once and used everywhere it is autowired in the application.

Since the `PartitionHandler` is being step-scoped, it causes the `PartitionHandler` to be created at the *beginning* of the step execution, at which point the `@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String table` parameter is null because job parameters have not been bound yet.
When the `PartitionHandler` then tries to create the worker step using this null `table` parameter, a null `STEP_EXECUTION_ID` is inserted into the `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` table, causing the error.

---

Try and remove `@StepScope` from the `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` method.

```java
@Bean
public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(String table) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    handler.setStep(IncrementalWorker(table));
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    try {
        handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return handler;
}
```

Also, in your `IncrementalXmlManager` method, it is necessary to use a bean expression to pass the `table` parameter to `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler`. Otherwise, the `table` parameter of `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` will not be populated and will be `null`.

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String table) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
            .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(table))
            .build();
}
```

---

I would also make sure the master and slave steps do *not* the same name, which can confuse Spring Batch's tracking mechanism.

Try ensuring that each step, including the partition step and the steps it partitions, has a unique name.

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String table) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
            .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(table))
            .build();
}
```

And make sure to set unique names for the steps in your `IncrementalWorker` method:

```java
@Bean
@StepScope
public Step IncrementalWorker(@Value("#{jobParameters['TName']}") String name) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalWorker-" + name)
            .<Table, Data>chunk(CHUNK_SIZE)
            .reader(oracleXmlIncrementalReader)
            .processor(new FastXmlProcessor())
            .writer(jsonWriter)
            .build();
}
```

By appending the table name (`table` or `name`) to the step names, we ensure each step has a unique name.

---

> I tried all those modifications, but it did not solve my problem.

True, but there is a small issue with the method `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler()`. In this method, you are calling `IncrementalWorker(null)`, which is causing a `null` job parameter to be passed to the `IncrementalWorker` bean.

In this context, `IncrementalWorker(null)` is not appropriate because it is expected to have a table name (or some string value) rather than `null`.

Instead, consider defining the `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler()` method in a way that accepts a `Step` as a parameter. That would allow you to pass the `IncrementalWorker` step directly when creating the partition step, like so:

```java
@Bean
public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(Step step) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    handler.setStep(step);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    handler.afterPropertiesSet();

    return handler;
}
```

And in the `IncrementalXmlManager` method, you can pass the `IncrementalWorker` bean like so:

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table,
                                  @Qualifier("IncrementalWorker") Step step) throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
            .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(step))
            .build();
}
```

That way, you ensure the `IncrementalWorker` bean is correctly instantiated with the expected parameters before it is used in the `PartitionHandler`.

In addition to this, I noticed that the `@StepScope` annotation is still present on the `partitioner()` bean. If you are not using late binding (i.e., using a job or step parameter in your bean), you should remove this annotation from the `partitioner()` method.

---

Regarding the error:

`Parameter 0 of method XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler in ExtracteurSteps required a single bean, but 9 were found:`

That message means Spring does not know which `Step` bean should be used in `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler`. The `@Qualifier` annotation with a value "`IncrementalWorker`" is not sufficient because Spring Boot creates a new `Step` bean for each job execution with a different parameter value, and all of them match the "`IncrementalWorker`" name...

To address this, you could use a [`StepLocator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/StepLocator.html) to retrieve the appropriate step at runtime.

Here is an updated version of your `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` method using `StepLocator`:

```java
@Bean
public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(StepLocator stepLocator) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    handler.setStep(stepLocator.getStep("IncrementalWorker"));  // change this to match the name of the step
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    return handler;
}
```

To use `StepLocator`, you will need to add it as a parameter to your `IncrementalXmlManager` method and pass it to the `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler`:

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table, 
                                  StepLocator stepLocator) throws Exception {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
            .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(stepLocator))
            .build();
}
```

Now, Spring will resolve the step at runtime, finding the right `Step` Bean based on its name.

Warning: the `StepLocator` will return the first step it finds that matches the given name. Therefore, it is critical that each `Step` bean has a *unique* name. If multiple `Step` beans share the same name, the `StepLocator` might not return the correct `Step`.

And make sure the step name provided in the `getStep()` method matches the name given when you define your `IncrementalWorker` step.

Then, try and remove the `@StepScope` from your `partitioner` Bean unless you are using late binding in this bean.

---

A `ScopeNotActiveException` exception means Spring is trying to create a bean that is Job scoped (i.e., it only lives within the context of a single job execution) during the application context initialization. That is problematic because there is no job execution at that point, hence the error that the job scope is not active.

The method `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` where you are using `StepLocator` to get your step, Spring is trying to create the bean during application context initialization. The solution to this problem is to move the `StepLocator` from the `PartitionHandler` method to the `IncrementalXmlManager` method where you are actually creating your job. That will defer the creation of the partition handler until a job is actually running, which should prevent the `ScopeNotActiveException`.

That would be:

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public Step IncrementalXmlManager(@Value("#{jobParameters['T_Selection_Name']}") String table, StepLocator stepLocator) throws Exception {
    Step step = stepLocator.getStep("IncrementalWorker");
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("IncrementalXmlManager-" + table)
            .partitioner("IncrementalWorker-" + table, partitioner())
            .partitionHandler(XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(step))
            .build();
}

@Bean
public PartitionHandler XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler(Step step) throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(GRID_SIZE);
    handler.setStep(step);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
    handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    return handler;
}
```

That code moves the `StepLocator` from `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler` to `IncrementalXmlManager`, and passes the `Step` directly to `XMLIncrementalPartitionHandler`. That ensures that the `Step` is not fetched until a job is actually running, which should fix the `ScopeNotActiveException` you were seeing.

Comment: As commented, i tried all those modifications but it did not solve my problem

Comment: i edited my question with the final version of my code, you can check it and thank you very much

Comment: @maryemneyli Do you get the same stack trace?

Comment: @maryemneyli I have edited the answer to comment on your latest code.

Comment: I modified my code and again encountered the same error unfortunately, but you should know that the simple steps work well for me (for example, if I only use `IncrementalWorker` as a step in my job, the application works, so when I add the partitioning part, it blocks things for me).

Comment: @maryemneyli OK, I have edited the answer to address your latest code revision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254495/discussion-between-maryem-neyli-and-vonc).

Comment: I edited my code but this time it generated a new error, you can see the stuck trace up, i updated my question.